# iAd rotation issue with UISplitView

Tags: ios, iad, uisplitview

I was testing the SplitNavigationBanner example in iAdSuite and noticed something strange.

If I had the iPad in portrait and tapped an ad it would load the ad fullscreen in landscape. When dismissing it and rotating it to portrait I end up with this

[image: iPad running iAdSuite]

It appears to be bug in the way Apple serve ads with an embedded `UIViewController`.

Has anyone else been faced with the same issue when implementing Apple's way of displaying banners with a `UISplitView`? Or is there a better way to do it?

[You can download the examples here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Introduction/Intro.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple engineers have stated it looks like a bug: https://devforums.apple.com/message/930887